# Oxalate ion dentiticity - why is it bidentate and not tetradentate?

Tags: coordination-compounds

Why is the oxalate ion a *bidentate ligand*? Why does it not act like a tetradentate ligand (having four oxygen atoms, with lone pairs)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The oxalate anion cannot be tetradentate. While there are four oxygen atoms, the ion is planar and the oxygen atoms are pointing in different directions.

[image]

The best any metal can do is bond to two of them, although there are two bonding modes possible:

[image]

[image]

Perhaps you were envisioning some $\kappa^4$-bonding mode that is 
"side-on". However, most of the nonbonding electrons (orbitals) are also in the plane.

This is not to say that oxalate cannot form four bonds to metal centers; it just cannot do so with only one metal center. Oxalate can act as a [bridging ligand](https://www.google.com/search?q=oxalate+bridging+ligand&oq=bridging+oxa&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l2.5158j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

[image]